# angular 7 response parser not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, single-page-application

hey i upgraded my angular from 4.4 to latest 7 
now after lots of error i got service to run finally 
 i have this out parser which parse the login response and return it 
but it isn't returning anything just empty body 
how can i fix that?

**Login service**

```
 this.http.post("/auth/login", JSON.stringify(payload), {}).subscribe(
    (resp: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      let body = this.outputParser(resp); //it is returning null
      this.sessionService.setAccessToken(body.AccessToken);
      this.sessionService.setUser(body.User);
    },
```

**output parser**

```
private outputParser(res: HttpResponse<any>) {
let responseText: any = res;
if (!responseText) {
  return null;
}
try {
  return JSON.parse(responseText);
} catch (e) {
  return null;
 }
}
```

and yes i wrote output parser before login service

how to solve this problem?
thanks

Comment: For HttpClient response, parsing is not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular 7, you are using **HttpClient** so you don't need to parse anything.

Try this:

```
let body = resp
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be more cleanner way for your code. You dont need to parse into json because by default angular return json format

```js
this.http.post("/auth/login", JSON.stringify(payload), {}).subscribe(
    (resp: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      this.sessionService.setAccessToken(resp.AccessToken);
      this.sessionService.setUser(resp.User);
    }
```

Cheers.